# Correct implementation for the log out functionality in ms teams applications

Tags: microsoft-teams

What is the recommended implementation for log out functionality in ms teams applications?
According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) I implemented SSO authentication and I added log out functionality (the same code like here (an example mentioned in the documentation): https://github.com/ydogandjiev/taskmeow/blob/19c1c11e6b5c303c08741f526c5aabafd2755a16/src/services/adal.auth.service.js#L61) associated with the log out button.
After clicking on the log out button in my ms teams application I get the following screen:

[image]

As you can see I'm still logged in ms teams (my credentials are visible and I can click the "Sign out" button). After refreshing the page ("Reload tab" button) I'm logged in my ms teams application and sign in screen doesn't appear.

Comment: What i understood - You have one custom app which you developed for Teams. You have implemented SSO on it. When you logout from the application (not teams), your Teams still shows that you are logged in and shows Sign out. Is it correct?
If my understanding about your problem statement is correct then, this is working fine because you arr logging out of your application and not Teams. This is correct behavior.

Comment: That's right - I'm trying to log out from my custom application written for ms teams. Following your answer I shouldn't have an opportunity to log out (sign out in ms teams nomenclature) directly from ms teams using my application. I can only log out from my application. Is that right? If yes, I would expect a different behaviour connected with logging out from my application - after logging out and reloding the page I should be forced to populate credentials instead of getting them by the SSO.

Comment: If this is the first time the current user has used your tab application, there will be a request prompt to consent  (if consent is required) or to handle step-up authentication (such as two-factor authentication) when SSO is implemented. Post to that it will never be prompted. Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso#how-sso-works-at-runtime) for more details on how SSO works